# How to format code in Visual Studio Code Polyglot Notebook?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When writing code (e.g. C#) in a cell of a Visual Studio Code Polyglot Notebook, is there a command or keyboard shortcut to format the code? I want to be able have code indented correctly.

Comment: how exactly do you want this to work? do you want the default formatter for each cell's language mode to apply for that cell?

Comment: I have the same interest. Pressing `shift+alt+f` does not automatically format my code but VSCode asks me to install `polyglot-notebook` formatter. It is really stupid. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Format Document** command to format the code in a cell. To use this command, you can either:

- Press **Shift + Alt + F** on Windows or **Shift + Option + F** on macOS.
- Right-click anywhere in the cell and select **Format Document** from the context menu.

This command will format the code in the cell according to the language-specific formatting rules. If you want to customize the formatting rules, you can create a **.editorconfig** file in the root directory of your project and specify the formatting rules for each language. For more information on how to create an **.editorconfig** file, please refer to the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/polyglot#_editorconfig-support).

Comment: I tried your suggestion of using Format Document, but this command results in Visual Studio Code asking to install a formatter. In this case, a formatter for the `polyglot-notebook`. I tried installing csharpier, which is a formatter for C#, but this did not get picked up. Perhaps I am missing a step still?